# Pythonの辞書とリスト

Tags: python

はじめまして、Python初心者のものです。
リストの中の要素と、元々用意してあったkeyの一つとを一致させてそのvalueを出したいのですが、うまくいきません。
教えていただけたら幸いです。

```
fruitnames = ["Apple", "Grape","Orange"]

fruitnumbers[fruitnumber,value] = ｛"Grape":2,"Strawberry":20,"Apple":10,"Orange":40}
def fruitcode():
    for fruitnumber in fruitnumbers:
          if fruitname == fruitnumber in fruitnumbers:
                  print(value,fruitname)

fruitcode()
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

気づいた問題点をあげてみます

１）「元々用意してあったkey」というのは、fruitnames = ["Apple", "Grape","Orange"]の事だと思われます。だとすれば、

```
for fruitnumber in fruitnumbers:
```

は、

```
for fruitname in fruitnames:
```

であるべきです。

２）「keyの一つとを一致させて」というのは、fruitnamesの中の一つのkeyが、fruitnumbersに含まれる（そのキーの項目を含む）という事でしょうから、

```
 if fruitname == fruitnumber in fruitnumbers:
```

は、

```
 if fruitname  in fruitnumbers:
```

(この行は、if fruitmembers.has_key(fruitname)　と書くこともできます。キーが含まれていたら(has key)という関数のほうが、意味が判り易くて良いかもしれません）

３）辞書のvalueは、辞書にキーを与えることで得られます。

```
print(value,fruitname)
```

は、

```
print(fruitnumbers[fruitname],fruitname)
```

fruitnumbers[fruitname]　で、fruitnumbersの中でキーがfruitnameと一致するもののvalueが得られます。

Comment: お早い回答ありがとうございます！ご指摘いただいた内容に変更いたしましたら解決しました(^^)とても助かりました！